# Hyperledger Composer - How to prevent a participant from changing certain attributes of their resource if they have UPDATE permission in acl?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

I coded an article submission system in the hyperledger composer that should basically allow an "Author" type participant to create an "Article" asset that should be reviewed by a reviewer (another "Author" attribute isReview = true).

The question is that following the logic of ACL, the Author can change their data and this includes the attribute that determines whether or not they are a reviewer. This should not be allowed because the author only becomes a reviewer when he publishes an article successfully.

My question is whether I need to restrict this in some way in the javascript logic of hyperledger or if I can mask this in the client application, if it can be done on the client, could a hacker make use of this "gap"?

I know I can do this in the client application, but I do not know the implications of this kind of approach, since the system should be all worked on the back end, because of security issues.

.cto

```
participant Author identified by email {
  o String authorId optional
  o String email
  o String firstName
  o String lastName
  o Boolean isReviewer default=false
  o Double points default=0.0
  o Double reputation default=0.0
}
```

.acl

```
  rule AuthorCanUpdateData {
      description: "Allow all author access to all resources"
      participant(m): "org.dasp.net.Author"
      operation: ALL
      resource(v): "org.dasp.net.Author"
      condition: (v.getIdentifier() == m.getIdentifier())
      action: ALLOW
  }
```

I hoped to be able to determine which feature attribute the participant can change or not. but I did not find any of this, just READ, UPDATE, CREATE AND ALL

Answer (score 0):

Hyperledger Composer does not have 'attribute level' authorization controls, it mainly controls which participants have restrictions on which resources (class, instance(s) etc) in the business network.

So - to the question asked: If you need attribute level control (and the 'author' is accessing the business network via a client app) - then yes, you should implement client side. The usual security architecture concerns apply here (sorry, I can't help you who should have access to your business network from a client, what orgs/peers need to endorse transactions etc etc).

As for restriction within the business network, it seems the question in short is: "can I prevent an unpublished author changing their `isReviewer` status specifically?"

Yes, you could restrict, by maintaining a separate status asset listing in this instance:

```
participant Author identified by email {
o String email
o String authorId optional
o String firstName
o String lastName
o Double points default=0.0
o Double reputation default=0.0
```

}

```
asset Authorship identified by authorId {
      o String authorId 
      o Boolean isReviewer default=false
    }
```

then your ACL (as it exists) would work ('author can edit own profile') as you're working at a resource level and your client can check reviewer status (if that's what it currently is doing ie whether someone has authority to review).